# How to import all my mail.ru messages to my gmail without spending a penny?

Tags: gmail

I know my question is easy to answer but problem is language(Russian).

By googling, I came to know only premium services will do the job.

I am edge of losing all mail.ru account.

I decided to set up gmail.

I want to import all messages(including folder) in mail.ru to my new gmail inbox.

Most of mail.ru tutorials are in Russian.

Comment: You can probably use the Chrome browser, it has a built-in translator for those Russian tutorials. Удачи!

Comment: So I won't get answer other than that? Should I wait to somebody attempt to answer it?

Comment: I don't know; I have no idea how hard this question is, how long you still have access to your account and how much time you have to try what I suggested...